# How to customize laravel array validation error keys and message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I use `FormRequest` in my app for validating data.

**Example code:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'skills' => "required|array",
            "skills.*" => "required|min:2|max:20"
        ];
    }
}
```

Here by default when I pass to request this example data:

```
{
    "skills" => [
        "a",
        "apple"
    ]
}
```

Then get error message:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "skills.0": [
            "The skills.0 must be at least 2 characters."
        ],

        "skills.1": [
            "The skills.1 may not be greater than 4 characters."
        ]
    }
}
```

How I can customize this validation error messages and get something like this errors on result:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "skills": [
            "The skills with key 0 must be at least 2 characters.",
            "The skills with key 1 may not be greater than 4 characters."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#customizing-the-error-messages

Comment: And how I can customize (rename) or remove error keys? @kerbholz

Comment: For the moment, I believe there is no clean solution to do get nested array error messages, like what you are looking for. You would need to override some methods on the `FormRequest::class` to get this behavior. There also isn't a clean way to retrieve the index of each error in array to define your message.

Comment: For API errors response something like this error keys `(skills.0, skills.1, skills.18)` is clean solution? @RobertKujawa

Comment: @AndreasHunter, that's how Laravel handles it out of the box, but it isn't very nice for the end user, I'm not sure how you are displaying the errors on your front end, but if you are doing it right below each input control, I usually just change the attribute name of my arrays, so that it looks good for the end user. You can do this by defining an attributes function on your `FormRequest`. `public function attributes() { return ['skills.*' => 'skill']; }` that way your error message would look like this: `"skills.0": ["The skill field must be at least 2 characters."]`

Comment: Yes, @RobertKujawa, attribute names can be renamed, but I don’t like such array keys `"skills.0"`

Comment: I understand @AndreasHunter, I don't like the keys either, its just an unnecessary pain, I use Vue as my frontend and bypass this issue by looping through my array, and constructing a string to fetch my error messages by the key. '<li v-for="(skill, index) in skills"><input type="text" :value="skill" /><p v-if="errors['skills.'+index].length">errors['skills.'+index]</p></li>' This allows me to display an error message below my selected form if the error exists.

Comment: Have you tried this `"skills.*.min" => "...","skills.*.max" => "...",` ?